# Setting default value for custom webpart property

Tags: web-part, custom-web-part-property

im trying to set a DefaultValue for my custom webpart property..

```
namespace Beraterprofil.VisualWebPart1
{
    [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
    public class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
    {
        private string _sectionToRead = "CV";

        [WebBrowsable(true), Category("Miscellaneous"), Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
            WebDisplayName("Welche Sektion soll gelesen werden?"), DefaultValue("CV")]
         public string sectionToRead
         {
             get { return _sectionToRead; }
             set { _sectionToRead = value; }            
         }
```

This is how i programmed it so far.  What really confuses me is when i'm debugging this my sectionToRead string always displays "SPS-Section-ContactInfo" and i can't figure out from where he gets this string value..

[image: Display of the Debug]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK, DefaultValue attribute won't work for webpart properties.

You can use **.webpart** file for setting default values to your properties. You will need to add new `<property>` element under `<properties>` tag, like following:

```
<property name="sectionToRead" type="string">CV</property>
```

Comment: i had used the string "SPS-Section-ContactInfo" yesterday for testing purposes and apparently it has been stored inside sharepoint and since then every time it has produced an server error so i wasn't able to change the custom property to a value which won't produce an error..

Comment: Webpart property is an attribute of the webpart instance, which you has added to a webpart page somewhere on the site. So, you can basically remove your webpart instance from the particular page (using `?contents=1` query string), and when you add it again, new webpart instance will be created, and default values will be applied.

Comment: Right, I was going to mention that if you change the value... it will never use the default again.

Comment: @AndreyMarkeev, is there a source describing why `DefaultValue` doesn't work with webpart properties? I ran into this exact problem today and of course ended coming up with a workaround for my solution.  I appreciate your answer that pointed me in the right direction, but I am curious as to *why* the DefaultValue setting seems to be ignored on Webparts.