# DefaultValue on WebPart Custom Properties

Tags: web-part, properties

I'm new to SharePoint and I'm developing a WebPart.

I'm trying to create some properties with a `DefaultValue`, but they stay null.

Here is how I'm defining my property in my class:

```
public static string titleWP;
[Category("Extended Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
DefaultValue("Résultats de recherche"),
WebDisplayName("Titres de la WebPart"),
WebDescription("Entrez le titre de la WebPart")]
public string _titleWP
{
    get { return titleWP; }
    set { titleWP = value; }
}
```

And in `CreateChildControls`, if I do this, I get an exception because `titleWP` is null

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleWP.Trim()))
{
    titleWP = "search result";
}
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Strange thing is if I do an IISRESET or `update-spsolution`(because make changes) the value that the users enter disappears and it retrieves the default value.

What is the best practice for defining a property and don't lose what the user modify?

Comment: aren't there a solution to put a default value?

And what appen if i modify the value (directly in the property in edit webpart from sharepoint).
The users has to keep the value they define in the property

Thanks

Comment: Your current approach is fine, your only problem is that you call `.Trim()` on a variable which can be null, you can solve this by `(titleWP ?? "").Trim()`. And this is initially, when users save the variable will have a value. I'm a bit baffled by your unconventional naming (underscore for property, none for private variable), but it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not store titleWP property as static (I think this is the reason why IISReset clears the value)

I would use something like this:

```
private const string DefaultTitleWP = "Résultats de recherche";
private string _titleWP = DefaultTitleWP;
[Category("Extended Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
DefaultValue(DefaultTitleWP)
WebDisplayName("Titres de la WebPart"),
WebDescription("Entrez le titre de la WebPart")]
public string TitleWP
{
    get { return _titleWP; }
    set { _titleWP = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `DefaultValue` works [very well](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/21348/627).

Try this:

```
titleWP = titleWP ?? "Résultats de recherche";
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleWP.Trim()))
{
    titleWP = "search result";
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want though, here if `titleWP` is null it will be _Résultats de recherche_, if `titleWP` is empty it will be _search result_. This seems strange to me, but it is according with your original code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(titleWP)
```

This will check null, empty or just white space (like row breaks and blanks)

Comment: Hoping for SharePoint 2013? :)

Comment: Always have hope;)